# Time slot inversion

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have an interesting time slot inversion algorithm that I am struggling to solve and hope I can get some help here. I have the following challenge:

We are working with Salesforce field service as our platform. Company sets the operating hours for days of the week, Monday to Sunday. Every day has an the start time and the end time. For instance
Mon - 8:00 to 22:00
Tue - 8:00 to 20:00
and so on

Because of a constraint of Salesforce, users can only say when their absent, not when they are available. So for instance, I can say I am unavailable between 13 - 16 on Monday by creating an absence record:

```
ResourceAbsence absence = new ResourceAbsence(StartTime=13, EndTime=16, Day = 'Monday');
```

Our company wants the user to be able to say when they are available, not unavailable. We need a function that inverts that so a user can say that they are available instead of unavailable:

```
ResourceAvailability availability1 = new Resource(StartTime=8, EndTime=13, Day = 'Monday');
ResourceAvailability availability2 = new Resource(StartTime=16, EndTime=22, Day = 'Monday');
```

The idea is that a user passes to a function a list of availability records and absences get returned. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: What is the salesforce constraint that forces people to only say absent time and not available time?

Comment: What have you tried so far to get this accomplished?

Comment: @ArunKumar it's a constraint of a newer product called Field Service Lightning. You can only set absences, not availability. So far haven't came up with anything

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you're not allowing for clock change days when there aren't 24 hours in a day. The algorithm would go something like this:

```
For each day of the week
    If a record doesn't exist, return absence(Starttime=0, enddtime=24, day = currentday
    else
        return absence(starttime=0, endtime=resource.starttime) and
            absence(starttime=resource.endtime, endtime=24)
```